# Create column store table using JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hana

I am trying to set up a table using JPA on HANA DB.

I would like to set the table as a column store (the default is row store).

Asking for your assistance, finding the annotation in order to set the table using the code instead of changing it manually every time.

Thanks.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
@IdClass(Account.class)
@Data
public class Account {

@Id
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 32)
protected String landscape;

@Id
@Column(name = "ACCOUNT", length = 32)
protected String accountName;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you can't. The document referenced at this link:

https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-28976

notes that:

> Column tables cannot be generated by JPA Entities as for now (no
>   provider’s support Column table annotations yet).

Comment: Hi, you can see my answer. I found that I can use Liquid Base. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a short investigate, I found that I can't use JPA but I have another solution using Liquid-Base.
Create change log and use the command of the column store:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">


    <changeSet author="myapplication" id="myid">
        <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <tableExists tableName="TABLE_NAME"/>
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <sql>

            ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME COLUMN

        </sql>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option would be to change the default table type from `row` to `column`.

This can be done by setting the parameter `default_table_type` in the `sql`-section of the `indexserver.ini` config file.

While the delivered default setting is `row` for SAP HANA 1 and for SAP HANA 2 up to SPS2, SAP changed the delivered default setting to `column` in SAP HANA 2 SPS3.

Comment: Thanks but I chose not to change the default settings in order not to affect other tables.

Comment: Fair call - however as nearly every use case is suitable for column store tables and only a few very specific cases need a row store table, the risk of having a table falsely in the column store is pretty small. Also, this setting only affects newly created tables that don’t come with a table store specification. Existing tables would not be changed if you change this setting.

Comment: Yes of course. I will reconsider it, maybe changing the default settings will be the right call anyway.